# CDK's CodePipeline or CodeBuildStep are leaving an S3 bucket behind, is there a way of automatically removing it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm creating a CloudFormation stack using CDK with code roughly like this:

```js
export class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props)
        new pipelines.CodePipeline(this, id, {
            pipelineName: id,
            synth: new pipelines.CodeBuildStep("Synth", {
                    input: pipelines.CodePipelineSource.connection(props.githubRepo, props.repoBranch, {connectionArn: props.repoConnectionArn}),
                    installCommands: ["npm install -g aws-cdk"],
                    commands: ["npm ci", "npx cdk synth"],
                },
            ),
        })
    }
}
```

and that stack creates an S3 bucket that when I delete the stack isn't deleted with it. I searched for options and I couldn't find any to control that behaviour. Is it possible to mark that S3 bucket as `cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the artifacts bucket. It can be accessed via the `CodePipeline.pipeline.artifactBucket`. You need to do this after you define the whole pipeline and call `myPipeline.buildPipeline();`

```js
myPipeline.buildPipeline();
const artifactBucket = myPipeline.pipeline.artifactBucket;
artifactBucket.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);
```

Documentation:

- [CodePipeline#pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.CodePipeline.html#pipeline)
- [Pipeline#artifactbucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline.Pipeline.html#artifactbucket-1)

Although this wouldn't solve the issue of the bucket being non-empty and failing to delete. To solve this properly, you need to create your own `Pipeline` with a bucket you create yourself and pass it to `CodePipeline`'s constructor in the `codePipeline` property:

```ts
const artifactBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'artifactBucket', {autoDeleteObjects: true});
artifactBucket.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY);

const underlyingPipeline = aws_codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'underlyingPipeline', {artifactBucket: artifactBucket});

const pipeline = pipelines.Codepipeline(this, 'myPipeline', {codePipeline:underlyingPipeline, ...});
```

Comment: That was very educational. Thank you. Wouldn't it also need the equivalent of `autoDeleteObjects: true`. I'm searching the API to see how to do that.

Comment: @pupeno it is the same in V1 and V2. The original answer said `.codepipeline`, while the correct property is `.pipeline` in both V1 and V2.

Comment: Ah... I'm using v2, so I didn't look too closely at the v1, I just left it as is and added what I got working with v2 based on what you taught me.

Comment: I updated the answer to address your comment about autoDeleteObjects

Comment: Although it is probably possible to achieve with an escape hatch overriding the property of the original bucket.

Comment: I also run out into `Error: Pipeline not created yet` with the original answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this error.